# Error in HEVC enconde of 16 bit depth : " enable RExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT"

Tags: hevc

I have an problem, when i enconde the imagem with 16 bit depth i obtain one error, the error is:

"enable RExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT";

I use the InternalBitDepth = 16 , i need use this.

I read what i need changed in TypeDef.h the next line :

#ifndef RExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT

#define RExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT    0 ///< 0 (default) use data type definitions for 8-10 bit video, 1 = use larger data types to allow for up to 16 bit video

I change to #define RExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT    1 ///, and i run the makefile, but the error remained.

Whats happen?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that HM supports the bit depth of 16? 
I am not sure about my claim; but I think every time I hear from someone about "higher bit depth in HM", they usually talk about 10 or at most 12 bit depth. 
As I said, I am not sure at all. Maybe it supports! 
If you'll find the answer, please share it with us.

Good luck

Comment: Yes the new version is enable for 16 bit, but dont is enable by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the main directory.
2. Open `CMakeList.txt`.
3. Find the line setting `HIGH_BITDEPTH`.
4. Change `OFF` to `ON` to enable `HIGH_BITDEPTH`.
5. In the building directory, delete `CMakeCache.txt`.
6. `cmake` again to rebuild to project.
7. Fix the warnings of shifting 32bit integers (change `1 <<` into `1ll <<`).

Done.